# Convert MonetaryAmount to long of minor units (Javamoney)

Tags: java, java-money

Using the JSR-354 Java Money API (Moneta in this case), I can easily create a `MonetaryAmount` object from a `long` of minor units (pence in this case):

```
MonetaryAmount amount = Money.ofMinor(Monetary.getCurrency("GBP"), 1234); //£12.34
```

...but how do I query this `MonetaryAmount` *back* for its minor units in the same way? I can do:

```
amount.getNumber().longValue();
```

...but that only gives the *major* units, truncating the minor units entirely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
long minorUnits = monetaryAmount.query(MonetaryQueries.convertMinorPart()); //1234
```

Other values on `MonetaryQueries` can also be used to *extract* just the minor part  if required (which would return `34` in the above case.)